# hline in table simply stops

Tags: tables

I have a very wide table in landscape format where the horizontal lines just stop.

How can I make the lines go to the end of the table normally?

```
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \hspace*{-83mm}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{1.4\linewidth}{|l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
         \hline
         \textbf{Objekt} & \textbf{Frequenz} & \textbf{Medium} & \textbf{Projektleiter} & \textbf{Auftraggeber} & \textbf{Fachgebietsleiter} & \textbf{Institutsleiter} & \textbf{ITSB/CIO} & \textbf{DSB} & \textbf{Lieferanten} & \textbf{Anwender} & \textbf{Mitarbeiter} & \textbf{FIMA} & \textbf{Einkauf} & \textbf{SCC} \\
         \hline\hline
         Statusbericht & monatlich & E-Mail & RA & I & & I & & & & I & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabularx}}
    \caption{Kommunikationsplan}
    \label{tab:kommunikationsplan}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

[image: Table with Problem]

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{1.4\linewidth}{|l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}` you have to have at least one X column in a tabularx

Comment: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%` only scale tables as a last resort 9and avoid doing it even then)

Comment: the hline is the specified with of the table (`1.4\linewidth`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have no X columns (and no linebreaking in the table) you should replace

```
\begin{tabularx}{1.4\linewidth}
```

by

```
\begin{tabular}
```

Then the table will be the natural width of its content and the `hline` will be that width. As it is you are forcing the table to be `1.4\linewidth` wide so the `hline` is that length even though the content is over-full so wider than the specified width.